# "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints" with UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I used the Interface Builder to create a pretty simple layout inside a `UITableViewCell` for my Xcode 13.0/Swift 5/iOS 13.5 app:

`UIStackView` (with 2 `UIView`s and `UILabel`s inside) at the top and a `UIView` (with a `UIImageView` inside) below it.

The exact constraints are currently:

- `UIStackView`: 10pts leading, 10pts trailing, 0pts top, 10pts to the `UIView` at the bottom, height of 50pts
- `UIView`: 20pts leading, 20pts trailing, 10pts bottom, (10pts top from the `UIStackView`), height=width
- `UIImageView` inside the `UIView`: 0pts leading/trailing/top/bottom, align center x to Superview (=`UIView`)

Contrary to other questions about the warning here on stackoverflow I don't set the `UITableViewCell`'s height directly but want it to be set by its content. The `UIImageView`'s image is set at runtime and should keep its shape, so square images should be square and the other rectangular images should be centered horizontally (-> invisible bars left/right, if necessary) but not vertically.

Xcode doesn't complain about missing constraints but this layout keeps giving me the infamous "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints" warning.

```
[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002d22d50 UIStackView:0x7fe4fa293330.height == 50   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002d22df0 UIView:0x7fe4fa29d1c0.height == UIView:0x7fe4fa29d1c0.width   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002d23070 V:|-(0)-[UIStackView:0x7fe4fa293330]   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe4fa2840f0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002d23110 H:[UIView:0x7fe4fa29d1c0]-(20)-|   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe4fa2840f0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002d23160 V:[UIStackView:0x7fe4fa293330]-(10)-[UIView:0x7fe4fa29d1c0]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002d231b0 H:|-(20)-[UIView:0x7fe4fa29d1c0]   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe4fa2840f0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002d23200 V:[UIView:0x7fe4fa29d1c0]-(10)-|   (active, names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe4fa2840f0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002d36530 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe4fa2840f0.height == 325.5   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002d364e0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe4fa2840f0.width == 295   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002d22df0 UIView:0x7fe4fa29d1c0.height == UIView:0x7fe4fa29d1c0.width   (active)>
```

I already checked with [wtfautolayout.com](https://www.wtfautolayout.com/?constraintlog=(%0A%20%20%20%20%22%3CNSLayoutConstraint:0x600002d22d50%20UIStackView:0x7fe4fa293330.height%20%3D%3D%2050%20%20%20(active)%3E%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%22%3CNSLayoutConstraint:0x600002d22df0%20UIView:0x7fe4fa29d1c0.height%20%3D%3D%20UIView:0x7fe4fa29d1c0.width%20%20%20(active)%3E%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%22%3CNSLayoutConstraint:0x600002d23070%20V:%7C-(0)-%5BUIStackView:0x7fe4fa293330%5D%20%20%20(active,%20names:%20%27%7C%27:UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe4fa2840f0%20)%3E%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%22%3CNSLayoutConstraint:0x600002d23110%20H:%5BUIView:0x7fe4fa29d1c0%5D-(20)-%7C%20%20%20(active,%20names:%20%27%7C%27:UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe4fa2840f0%20)%3E%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%22%3CNSLayoutConstraint:0x600002d23160%20V:%5BUIStackView:0x7fe4fa293330%5D-(10)-%5BUIView:0x7fe4fa29d1c0%5D%20%20%20(active)%3E%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%22%3CNSLayoutConstraint:0x600002d231b0%20H:%7C-(20)-%5BUIView:0x7fe4fa29d1c0%5D%20%20%20(active,%20names:%20%27%7C%27:UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe4fa2840f0%20)%3E%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%22%3CNSLayoutConstraint:0x600002d23200%20V:%5BUIView:0x7fe4fa29d1c0%5D-(10)-%7C%20%20%20(active,%20names:%20%27%7C%27:UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe4fa2840f0%20)%3E%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%22%3CNSLayoutConstraint:0x600002d36530%20%27UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height%27%20UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe4fa2840f0.height%20%3D%3D%20325.5%20%20%20(active)%3E%22,%0A%20%20%20%20%22%3CNSLayoutConstraint:0x600002d364e0%20%27UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width%27%20UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe4fa2840f0.width%20%3D%3D%20295%20%20%20(active)%3E%22%0A)) but the only thing wrong that I can see is the height: If the width is 295, then the height should be exactly 50+10+295-40+10=325 (UIStackView.height + constraint in-between + UIView.width - leading/trailing constraints + bottom constraint), not 325.5. Everything else looks fine to me, so I'm not sure why it would calculate that wrong height (and if that's even the problem).

I already tried a couple of things:

- Added the `UIStackView`'s fixed height (didn't use it before everything looked fine and it didn't complain about it, still got the warning though)
- `UIView.width = UIImageView.height` (1:1 aspect ratio, instead of the one above)
- `UIImageView.width = UIImageView.height` (1:1 aspect ratio, instead of the one above)
- Removed the "center x" constraint

Nothing worked, I keep getting the constraint warning and if it doesn't show up in portrait mode because of something I changed, then it does as soon as I switch to landscape mode. How do I fix this in IB/without code?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the priority of the height=width constraint to *High* instead of *Required*

Comment: Interesting, no more warning, thanks. But why does it work? Is there still a hidden conflict but I'm telling it to just ignore it with the different priority?

Comment: Probably so. But it might be a temporary conflict that exists only in a certain point in time while the ui elements are still not rendered.

Answer (score -1):

I had this error with **Table** together with **TableColumnCustomization** and using a **task** that was calling async update on a view model. The error was happening when I was **reordering columns** in the Table eventually crashing the application.

In the view model I was using following code to periodically update the published collection:

```
let newTimer = Timer(timeInterval: Double(intervalStr)!, repeats: true) { newTimer in
            self.mySyncFunction()    // Synchronous
            newTimer.invalidate()
            self.startTimer()
  }
  RunLoop.current.add(newTimer, forMode: .common)
```

Changing **forMode** to **.default** resolved the problem. Very specific scenario but leaving it here, maybe it helps someone else.